# JS function call works

Tags: javascript

I have question about the fundamentals of JS.

So, in JS we all agree that a function is an object. So lets suppose this:

```
const mainFunction = () => { //Do stuff };

mainFunction.nested = () => { //Do other stuff };
```

So I have two functions:

- a main function which I can call like this: `mainFunction()`
- and a nested function I can call like this: `mainFunction.nested()`

I quite understand that I can access to the nested function, because she is inside an object and I'm accessing it with `.` like JS syntax wants to.

But I'm wondering how can JS understand which code to run when I just call `mainFunction()` ?

Let me know if I'm clear enough, Its kind of a silly question...

Thanks

Comment: Code inside the mainFunction will be executed . The inner property function will not be executed until and unless you are dont call it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and a nested function I can call like this: mainFunction.nested()

It's not a nested function. This is a nested function:

```
function example() {
    function nested() {
    }
}
```

It's just a function assigned to a property.

> But I'm wondering how can JS understand which code to run when I just call `mainFunction()` ?

Because there's no ambiguity, you're referring to `mainFunction`. If you wanted to use the other function, you'd refer to it itself (the way you showed, `mainFunction.nested()`). It's exactly how there's no ambiguity between `obj` and `obj.prop`; the former refers to the object, the latter refers to the object's property.